# What does import class.1 mean?

Tags: java, class, import, constructor

I have found something like this in someone's code, and wondering what this exactly does?

```
import some.package.MyClass.1;
```

And then it is called by constructor:

```
new 1(some, arguments);
```

This code is within MyClass class.

```
import some.package.MyClass.1;
class MyClass {

  public MyClass() {
  }

  doSomethig(){
    someOperations...
    Files.walkFileTree(root, new 1(this, destination));
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
This code is coming from de-compiling a jar file.
As posted below -this could be a reason of such behavior.

Comment: It means nothing. It doesn't compile. Have you omitted a `$`?

Comment: `1` is not a valid identifier in Java. This code does not compile. If it did compile (maybe it was `_1` or `l` or such), there is no special meaning, it is just an (unusual) name of a class.

Comment: Nope. This is a class which I received by de-compiling a jar file. Is there a chance it appeared because of that ?

Comment: The code may have been obfuscated. Decompiling such classes has chances to give non compilable code .

Comment: Ah ... that explains it.  Decompilers are not guaranteed to generate valid Java code.

Answer (score 0):

It means someone has made a mistake as `1` is not a valid identifier in Java. Perhaps someone who shared this code with you wanted to obscure his class names and replaced the original name with "1".

> An identifier is an unlimited-length sequence of Java letters and Java digits, **the first of which must be a Java letter**
>
> [...]
>
> The "Java letters" include uppercase and lowercase ASCII Latin letters A-Z (\u0041-\u005a), and a-z (\u0061-\u007a), and, for historical reasons, the ASCII underscore (_, or \u005f) and dollar sign ($, or \u0024). The $ character should be used only in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy systems.

Documentation: [Identifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8)